# Android/iOS: How to provide SSO for mobile devices with Azure AD using SAML protocol

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement SSO in mobile native devices with Azure AD using SAML 2.0 protocol. From web I can successfully login but I am not finding a way to do the same using mobile client. I tried using Android project provided by Microsoft Azure  [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android). I was able to get the token using this project. But I don't understand what needs to be done next. Our previous request was something like this (without Azure):
https://myssodomain.com/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=SomeCodehere. A call to this request use to give me a SAMLResponse, which I used in redirect URL, and in return it used to provide me User profile details. Now, as in Azure the mechanism is quite different, I don't understand how should I proceed after I receive access token. How should I make a call to above URL to get SAMLResponse code so that I can use is to fetch User profile from the service provider.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol diagram below describes the single sign-on sequence. The cloud service (the service provider) uses an HTTP Redirect binding to pass an AuthnRequest (authentication request) element to Azure AD (the identity provider). Azure AD then uses an HTTP post binding to post a Response element to the cloud service.

[image]

To request a user authentication, cloud services send an AuthnRequest element to Azure AD. A sample SAML 2.0 AuthnRequest could look like the following example:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
ID="id6c1c178c166d486687be4aaf5e482730"
Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2013-03-18T03:28:54.1839884Z"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://www.contoso.com</Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

When a requested sign-on completes successfully, Azure AD posts a response to the cloud service. A response to a successful sign-on attempt looks like the following sample:

```
<samlp:Response ID="_a4958bfd-e107-4e67-b06d-0d85ade2e76a" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2013-03-18T07:38:15.144Z" Destination="https://contoso.com/identity/inboundsso.aspx" InResponseTo="id758d0ef385634593a77bdf7e632984b6" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> https://login.microsoftonline.com/82869000-6ad1-48f0-8171-272ed18796e9/</Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="https://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    ...
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
  </samlp:Status>
  <Assertion ID="_bf9c623d-cc20-407a-9a59-c2d0aee84d12" IssueInstant="2013-03-18T07:38:15.144Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <Issuer>https://login.microsoftonline.com/82869000-6ad1-48f0-8171-272ed18796e9/</Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="https://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      ...
    </ds:Signature>
    <Subject>
      <NameID>Uz2Pqz1X7pxe4XLWxV9KJQ+n59d573SepSAkuYKSde8=</NameID>
      <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id758d0ef385634593a77bdf7e632984b6" NotOnOrAfter="2013-03-18T07:43:15.144Z" Recipient="https://contoso.com/identity/inboundsso.aspx" />
      </SubjectConfirmation>
    </Subject>
    <Conditions NotBefore="2013-03-18T07:38:15.128Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-03-18T08:48:15.128Z">
      <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>https://www.contoso.com</Audience>
      </AudienceRestriction>
    </Conditions>
    <AttributeStatement>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
        <AttributeValue>testuser@contoso.com</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
        <AttributeValue>3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      ...
    </AttributeStatement>
    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2013-03-18T07:33:56.000Z" SessionIndex="_bf9c623d-cc20-407a-9a59-c2d0aee84d12">
      <AuthnContext>
        <AuthnContextClassRef> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
      </AuthnContext>
    </AuthnStatement>
  </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

The Response element includes the result of the authorization request. Azure AD sets the ID, Version and IssueInstant values in the Response element. It also sets the following attributes:

•   Destination: When sign-on completes successfully, this is set to the RedirectUri of the service provider (cloud service).

•   InResponseTo: This is set to the ID attribute of the AuthnRequest element that initiated the response.

For further documentation, you can refer below threads

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-protocol-reference

SAML Protocol requires the identity provider (Azure AD) and the service provider (the application) to exchange information about themselves.

// Perform authentication requests
mAuthContext.acquireToken(
    getActivity(), 
    RESOURCE_ID, 
    CLIENT_ID, 
    REDIRECT_URI,
    PromptBehavior.Auto, 
    getAuthInteractiveCallback());

// ...

// Get tokens to call APIs like the Microsoft Graph
mAuthResult.getAccessToken()

Once you have the token , you can use that to call graph api.

Here we have a wiki for setting up SSO in android , you might be interested.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/wiki

Hope it helps.